# Get parent collection from document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is there a way to get the collection name that a document is associated with from the document itself in MongoDB/Meteor? Something like document.collection? Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: No. There is no way to do that. But how would you get that document in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this, I assume that not only in Meteor, but in any library. The reason behind this, is that before getting the document, you already have done something like `db.collection.find()` and therefore already know which collection it belongs to.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I'm basically trying to create a global delete method that can be used to delete any record. If I had the collection name I could just pass that in and be able to do this, but I guess not.